# Popen in a function is blocking that function from being executed in a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to execute a binary from a python program (under Linux) and would like to dedicate this to a separate thread. Edit: The binary will run for quite a while and write data to disk. It would be nice if I could retreive stdout and stderr in python so that I can write this to a log. It would also be nice if I could evaluate the return value of the binary to make sure that it succeeds.

However, as soon as the function that I start with the thread contains the Popen statement, the thread doesn't seem to start at all :-( Is that a weird thing about thread safety that I don't understand? As soon as I comment out the part where the external command is called, the function is called fine....

Here is a minimum version of my code, I'm using python 2.7.9:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess
import sys
from threading import Thread


def record ( _command):
    print "Starting function"
    print "Now executing the following command: " + _command
    sys.stdout.flush()

#Here starts the interesting part. As long as this parts is part of the function, the function is not started at all.
#Not even the two lines before are executed :-(
#If I comment out the following lines, at least the print statements work
    process = Popen([_command], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout_lines = iter(process.stdout.readline, "")
    for stdout_line in stdout_lines:
        yield stdout_line

    process.stdout.close()
    return_code = process.wait()
    if return_code != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, _command)


###########################
#Main function starts here#
###########################
threads=[]
for i in range (0,5):
    t=Thread(target=record,args=('ls',))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

# wait for all threads to finish
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting skript"
```

This code just prints out:

```
Exiting skript
```

As soon as I comment out the Popen part, I get:

```
Starting function
Now executing the following command: ls
Starting function
Now executing the following command: ls
Starting function
Now executing the following command: ls
Starting function
Now executing the following command: ls
```

Starting function
    Now executing the following command: ls

```
Exiting skript
```

Comment: don't pass a generator function to a thread. How do you retrieve the data? `record` returns at the first `yield`

Comment: So the main problem lays in the yield statement rather than the Popen. Got it.

Comment: But I have to admit that I still don't understand why the first two print statements are not executed in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, you have a point. But your code logic is wrong. I woudn't waste too much time trying to understand why an illogic thing does illogic things. And maybe it's just that the output is buffered. Try `sys.stdout.flush()` after the 2 print lines. Also `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE` in `Popen` can lead to deadlock.

Comment: sys.stdout.flush() did not change anything. Do you have any specific advice on how to approach this problem better?  The background is that I need to start a few long running bash commands.

Comment: yes, but you have to be more specific: where do you want to store the output to? or you don't care about the output of the commands? Please edit your question.

Comment: I'd like to write the output to a logfile along with other information from the python program (that's why I'd like to get the output to the python program first). I just edited the my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some small fixes, your code runs:

- got rid of the generator function, doesn't make sense with threads
- simplified the way to get output from the process, but still read line by line (reading the final output with `communicate` would work but you seem to require having the lines printed immediately to have an idea of the current progress)
- protected output using a `Lock` or it would be mixed up between threads
- merged stdout and stderr in pipe to avoid deadlocks

fixed code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import subprocess
import sys
from threading import Thread,Lock

lck = Lock()

def record ( _command):
    lck.acquire()
    print("Starting function")
    print("Now executing the following command: " + _command)
    lck.release()

    process = Popen([_command], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if len(line)==0:
            break
        lck.acquire()
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        lck.release()

    process.wait()
    return_code = process.wait()
    if return_code != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, _command)

# main program

threads=[]
for i in range (0,5):
      t=Thread(target=record,args=('ls',))
      threads.append(t)
      t.start()

# wait for all threads to finish
for t in threads:
      t.join()
print("Exiting skript")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `record` function doesn't work as intended not because of the `Popen` call but because it's a generator function (because it contains a `yield` statement). Generator functions don't actually run their code when you call them. Instead, they return a generator object immediately, and the code in the function is run only when the generator object is iterated on.

I don't think there's any useful way to call a generator function directly as the target of a thread. Instead, you might want the thread to target some other function that consumes a generator object. Or you could restructure your current function to not be a generator (it's not obvious what the purpose of the `yield` statements was).

Comment: Thanks for making this so explicit. This was exactly the knot in my brain that I needed to solve :-)